# Working with Hashmap<String,double[]> in Android

Tags: java, android-xml

I am parsing XML file and writing data to hashmap, but when I am using the below code I am facing the error

> "The method put(String, Double[]) in the type HashMap
>   is not applicable for the arguments (String, double)"

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Double[]>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Double[]>>();
for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {                            

HashMap<String, Double[]> map = new HashMap<String, Double[]>();
Element e = (Element)children.item(i);
    HashMap<String, Double[]> map = new HashMap<String, Double[]>();
    map.put("id",(Double.parseDouble(ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "EMP_ID"))));
    mylist.add(map);
}
```

How do I change so that it would match with the method definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because this line:

```
map.put("id",(Double.parseDouble(ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "EMP_ID"))));
```

Is trying to put a "Double" type in a map which expects a "Double[]" type.  The following would be correct:

```
map.put("id",new Double[] { Double.valueOf(ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "EMP_ID")) });
```

because you're wrapping the single value into an array, which matches the type expected in your map.

Comment: Hi Matt
Thanks a lot it worked, I am facing the similar problem
while retrieving the data and assigning it to List<Double> it throws the error "The method add(Double) in the type List<Double> is not applicable for the arguments (Double[])"

ArrayList<HashMap<String, Double[]>> arl =(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Double[]>>)pd.getArrayList();
List<Double> empid = new ArrayList<Double>();
Iterator itr = arl.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
       HashMap< String,Double[]> map = (HashMap<String,Double[]>) itr.next();
       empid.add( map.get("id"));
      }
Request your ideas.
Thanks
Santosh

Answer (score 0):

Since you are storing Double in value.

Change

```
HashMap<String, Double[]> map = new HashMap<String, Double[]>();
```

To

```
HashMap<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String, Double>();
```

Comment: Hi Vipul

Thanks for the quick response.
I tried that when I do that it throws below syntax error near mylist.add(map) as my Arraylist is of type 
HashMap<String,Double[]

The method addAll(Collection<? extends HashMap<String,Double[]>>) in the type ArrayList<HashMap<String,Double[]>> is not applicable for the arguments (HashMap<String,Double>)

Thanks
Santosh